# Error in creating an SQLite database using the Python subprocess module

Tags: python, sqlite

The following Python code tries to create an SQLite database and a table, using the command line in Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import subprocess

args = ["sqlite3", "db.sqlite", "'CREATE TABLE my_table(my_column TEXT)'"]
print(" ".join(args))

subprocess.call(args)
```

When I ran the code, it created a database with zero bytes and the following output:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite 'CREATE TABLE my_table(my_column TEXT)'
Error: near "'CREATE TABLE my_table(my_column TEXT)'": syntax error
```

But when I copied the command printed by the code (just above the error message), and pasted the command onto the command line, the command created a database with a table.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: We should also say: Python has a built in module to handle sqlite: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html That's likely to be much cleaner than calling a separate process to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `'` in the second argument to `sqlite` (third element of the `args` list). The `subprocess` module does the quoting on its own and ensures, that the arguments gets passed to the executable as one string. It works on the command line, because there, the `'` are necessary to tell the shell, that it should treat the enclosed string as single entity.

```
args = ["sqlite3", "db.sqlite", "CREATE TABLE my_table(my_column TEXT)"]
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the extra quoting that @Dirk mentions before, you can also create the database without spawning a subprocess:

```
import sqlite3

cnx = sqlite3.connect("e:/temp/db.sqlite")
cnx.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table(my_column TEXT)")
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: You might want to note that SQLite creates a database if you attempt to connect to one that does not exist.